# flask-security-too with peewee + mysql not working

Tags: python, mysql, flask, peewee

After beating my head against the wall for a bit, I've decided I need help from the gurus here on stackoverflow.  It's very possible I'm missing something incredibly obvious.

I'm attempting to work with `Flask-Security-Too` since `Flask-Security` appears idle.

I used the code in the peewee database quick start (https://flask-security-too.readthedocs.io/en/stable/quickstart.html#basic-peewee-application) and everything worked as expected.  I swapped the `peewee.SqliteDatabase` for `peewee.MySQLDatabase` and I can no longer login.

To verify the `MySQL` connection was actually working, I added this simple code block after the connection initialized.

```
db = FlaskDB(app)

query = User.select()
for user in query:
   print(user.email)
```

When I start the flask server, the application prints out the user's email addresses in both the `SQLite` and `MySQL` configuration.  So it makes me think the issues isn't with the `MySQL` connection params.

One interesting tidbit, I turned on the `MySQL` general_log to 100% verify that the application was in fact querying the database.  When I've already logged in via the SQLite config, then switch the connection over to MySQL but still have the session cookie, it will query the `MySQL` database looking for the user in the session cookie (query below).  When I delete the session cookie and attempt to login, I see connections to the `MySQL` database but no queries.

Here is the `MySQL` query when I have a session cookie after logging in via SQLite.

```
SELECT `t1`.`id`, `t1`.`email`, `t1`.`password`, `t1`.`active`, `t1`.`fs_uniquifier`, `t1`.`confirmed_at` FROM `user` AS `t1` WHERE (`t1`.`fs_uniquifier` = '908d836c5d7845eaaa0a8637e7c4229b') LIMIT 1 OFFSET 0
```

Here is the connection entry for `MySQL` with no queries.  It just connects and quits.

```
Connect   root@10.42.0.15 on training using TCP/IP
Query     SET sql_mode='PIPES_AS_CONCAT'
Query     SET AUTOCOMMIT = 0
Quit
```

`Flask-Security-Too` will throw an error message on the `MySQL` login attempt that "Specified user does not exist" (which I think is an OWASP issue but that's a different concern).  Since it didn't query the database, it makes sense that it wouldn't find the user.  But why isn't it querying the database?!?

I checked the peewee database object between `SQLlite` and `MySQL` and see no differences.  Getting excited that I might be able to contribute to an opensource project, I started browsing the code in `Flask-Security-Too` but I don't see an obvious issue there either.  I'm stumped.  Hoping someone else has hit this issue and could give me some guidance.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Since I may not have made it obvious in the initial post, I just edited my question to add the peewee tag and mention peewee in the post title.

Comment: Could you provide more code details ? Your peewee setup ? How you initialize flask, peewee and flask-security-too ?

Comment: I literally copy pasted from the quickstart guide linked above and just swapped out the peewee SQLite connection params for MySQL connection params.  I verified that I had a valid connection to MySQL with the query above.

I hate to admit it, but after spending a lot of time digging into the depths of Flask-Security-Too, I gave up and switched to implementing Flask-Login directly.  I have that working now.

Comment: Perfect then, can you explain what you did in your own answer so it can be considered as done ?

Comment: I don't think I can "consider it done" since I abandoned Flask-Security-Too and went with Flask-Login.  I could be wrong, but right now I believe there is still an issue with either the tutorial docs or with Flask-Security-Too that will cause developers to abandon the module when it doesn't work with Peewee + MySQL.